# How do I place one section partially over another in mjml?

Tags: css, mjml

I would like to place one section on top of another how do I do that ? Using css-class seems to not work.

```
<mj-section full-width="full-width" background-color="#6B6B6B" padding-bottom="74px">
</mj-section>

<mj-wrapper background-color="#cccccc" padding-bottom="74px">
</mj-wrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

MJML doesn't directly support this.

I've seen some hacky techniques and some simulated attempts, but I wouldn't trust any to be consistent in all the email clients MJML authors want to support.

Can you use a simpler design, maybe? It'd be more reliable.